# Golden Gate Privilege Missing for using Encryption

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-golden-gate

> dblogin userid ogg_user, password AADAAAAAAAAAAAIAKAQIJAGAMFUFKFBGQHXBJIWGECTEIAZHJFYALFFIBGHGJBPFBCPBKEPCRCRHAESJ, AES128, encryptkey securekey1 ERROR: Unable to connect to database using user ogg_user. Please check privileges. ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

GoldenGate Version - 12.1.2.0.0
Database Version - 11.2.0.4

What are the privileges required to get the connection done. I have given all required for a Goldengate User including DBA, but still there is an error.

Let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone is there who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just missed a sense of error message: "ORA-01017: invalid username/password".
You need to check that password you encrypted as "AADAAAAAAAAAAAIAKAQIJAGAMFUFKFBGQHXBJIWGECTEIAZHJFYALFFIBGHGJBPFBCPBKEPCRCRHAESJ" is the same as password of "ogg_user" user in your database.
If you had a problem with privileges or so you'd get another error messages.

Please, set password in database to some value, encrypt it again and everything should be fine, I believe.

Good luck